# Wrong mpi number of processors

Tags: mpi, processors

Sorry, I'm sure making a silly mistake, but did not work out.

I'm compiling a simple mpi hello world:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main (argc, argv)
     int argc;
     char *argv[];
{
  int rank, size;

  MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);      /* starts MPI */
  MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);        /* get current process id */
  MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);        /* get number of processes */
  printf( "Hello world from process %d of %d\n", rank, size );
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

And:

```
> mpicc -o hello_world_c hello_world.c
> mpirun -np 4 hello_world_c
```

But returns:

```
Hello world from process 0 of 1
Hello world from process 0 of 1
Hello world from process 0 of 1
Hello world from process 0 of 1
```

But my computer is a core i7 with 4 cores. And everything seems to be ok, ie. cat /proc/cpuinfo shows the 4 processors

what's happening???
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Doesn't look like it's a problem with your MPI code. Which MPI library did you install? How did you install it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MPI\_Rank return same process number for all process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287564/mpi-rank-return-same-process-number-for-all-process)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.
The only problem that can be is with your mpi installation.

Notice:

There is a differences between processor to core. its not the same thing.

Comment: How did you install it? what computer do you use? do you use win7?

Comment: no no, I use Ubuntu and a regular installation. Package mpich2

Comment: Let me just add to this: the particular problem with the installation you're seeing here is probably that you're running your program with an mpirun which belongs to a different mpi installation than you compiled linked with.    Make sure the same mpirun, mpicc, and your mpi libraries are first in your various paths.

Comment: Thanks everybody. The problem was two mpi installation. mpich2 and openmpi. I uninstall openmpi and everything works fine. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need mpiexec from the 'mpich2' package.

Firstly, remove all mpi packages that installed on your computer.
If your server is Ubuntu, you can use the command:

```
sudo apt-get purge mpi mpich2 openmpi-common
```

To make sure that you have removed all the packages, try this command

```
which mpiexec
```

If you got nothing in response, you already removed all the packages.

Then reinstall the package of mpich2

```
sudo apt-get install mpich2
```

Try to compile and run your code again!
Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can compile it:

```
 int main (argc, argv)
 int argc;
 char *argv[];
```

will be changed to

```
 int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

another point is that mpi is message passing interface that passes messages between processes not cores or processors if you have a 4 core system you can run your code with so many processes as your ram permits but only 4 processes are working at any time and other processes must wait so it is efficient that you use only 4 process.

Answer (score 0):

**INSTALL**

```
sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dev openmpi-bin openmpi-doc
```

**Now compile and execute code**

[image]